# Meaning of puzzling sentence

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

What is the meaning of the sentence below?

> Anyone using WhatsApp through their desktop browser could have had their messages silently snooped on and their accounts completely hijacked in the last two years, security researchers warned Wednesday.

Comment: Please be more specific about which part(s) of the sentence are confusing you, and also describe what research you performed to try to the answer the question before you asked it here. You may find the [_Details, Please_ meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) to be helpful reading – please look it over and heed the advice there.

Answer (score 1):

It means that anyone who used WhatsApp on their computer (not their phone) might have been spied on.  Their messages may have been read by other (snooped on) or others may have taken control of their accounts (had their accounts hijacked).

Comment: Is it a possility or speculation?

Comment: It's meant to scare people, but is likely untrue.  Words like "warned" and "could have" mean that they're unsure.  It's possible that this has happened, but whoever the writer is is unsure.  I'd say this is speculation.

Comment: "@Scottish, "speculation" might not be an accurate word for this.  Speculation is guessing what might have actually happened.  The writer of your quote is suggesting a possibility that could potentially have happened, but not speculating on whether it actually did.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try and simplify it.

Any person who has used WhatsApp (you know, the social network?) may have had their messages read without their permission and they didn't know.  Their accounts could have been taken over and controlled by someone else in the last 2 years.  Security researchers (people who research things and are generally active in the security industry) warned about this on Wednesday.